# How to use the TreeMap.put without return value?

Tags: java, android

I've updated everything of my Android Studio, now my TreeMap is kind of ...different?

I don't know what API level I'm using but it appears that whenever I want to call the put method of the TreeMap template, I need to provide something for it to return a value to.

In other words, in the old days I could just:

```
TreeMap<LicenseNumber,Car> carsToStoreInMechnizedLot = new TreeMap<LicenseNumber,Car>();

carsToStoreInMechnizedLot.put("6CAL146","clubCar");
```

Now I must:

```
TreeMap<LicenseNumber,Car> carsToStoreInMechnizedLot = new TreeMap<LicenseNumber,Car>();

Car carReturnVal = carsToStoreInMechnizedLot.put("6CAL146","clubCar");
```

This is quite weird? Especially if you consider that the return value isn't something representing "successful" or "unsuccessful" but the value of the last element up the tree?

Am I doing something egregiously wrong?

Comment: Are you getting a compilation error when you ignore the return value of `put`?

Comment: Yes. Which is completely weird. I must have done something wrong when updating the studio.

Comment: Are LicenseNumber and Car - Strings? What error message gives the compiler?

Comment: @StefanLoKranDotti "Error:(55, 16) error: <identifier> expected" "Error:(55, 17) error: illegal start of type"  This is why I hate Android Studio. Every now and then right after updates I need to deal with some sort of setbacks.

Comment: @StefanLoKranDotti the time I read "illegal start of type" I control - clicked back to its definition thinking "it couldn't possibly be..." but there it is. Apparently I cannot ignore the last value up one level in the tree. I used to be able to.

Answer (score 1):

> whenever I want to call the put method of the TreeMap template, I
>   need to provide something for it to return a value to

Java doesn't force you to use the return of a method invocation.
But when you are using Android Studio, lint and IDE inspections run at each build.

Severity of lint and IDE inspections may produce warnings to errors.
Their goal is improving your code.

In many cases, it makes sense. But in some others, not really.
In your case, using the returning value of the `Map.put()` is strongly depending on the requirement of the processing.
So, if you don't need to consume the returned value, you should not obey to this rule but suppress this warning or disable this rule.

 More info on [Improve Your Code with Lint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html).

Comment: "but suppress this warning" the thing is, it kinda show up as an error instead of a warning...

Answer (score 0):

Signature of TreeMap put method is as below. In fact it is in Map interface.

```
public V put(K key,
    V value)
```

If you do not need to use the previous value which TreeMap returns, you simple ignore it and not assign to any variable.

Comment: Ideally that's true. But for some reason I must do the return value thing. I don't know what's wrong with the Android Studio.